# Invitation using a token

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am trying to implement an invitation system in Asp.NET where the user can add their email address and the system will send a security key to the e-mail in a link. When the user clicks the link he can register a new account. The problem is I cannot think of a way to mark the key as already used.

Comment: Do you store KEY in DB ?

Comment: I am still brainstorming about it but i can easily store it and when it is used remove it is their a butter way

Comment: Your question is *far* too broad, there are so many ways this can be done. If you have a particular strategy/design/implementation in mind please be more specific about what you are trying to do and demonstrate what you have already tried. Otherwise your question comes across as *"Please write code for me"* which isn't what this site is about.

Comment: @James I did not ask for writing code i am asking for ideas

Comment: @MohamedAbbas so you are looking for a *general* answer? Not one related to a particular framework / technology? If so then why tag the question as `C#` / `ASP.NET`...Also, if that *is* the case then you should really look at asking this over on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/) because there are various security implications you need to consider.

Comment: @Jame Thanks for pointing me to http://security.stackexchange.com/. I mentioned in my question that i am working in ASP.NET WEB API so i need ideas in the same context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the invitation KEY against your each unique email ID list.

So when user register using your KEY you can either remove that email form Pending Invitation List or alternatively use flag bit to mark as registered.